# Install R on the nodes for Azure batch services

Tags: r, virtual-machine, pool, azure-batch

I can create the batch service resources using Power shell as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-powershell-cmdlets-get-started

I want to run a R script on the nodes and I need R installed on the nodes as none of the available VM's(windows or linux) come with R installed. I have currently installed R by manually logging into the VM. But I want to create the batch resources and then install R on the nodes preferably through a script before I run the R code. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 main ways to load necessary software on to VMs:

1. Create a [start task](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/jobs-and-tasks#start-task) along with potentially [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/resource-files) to prep the compute node per your requirements.
2. Create a [custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-sig-images) that already contains all of your software preconfigured.
3. Use [containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-docker-container-workloads) instead of directly loading software on the compute node.
4. Utilize [application packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-application-packages).